# Render notebook as Reveal slideshow in JupyterLab, 404 : Not Found

Tags: jupyter-lab, reveal.js, rise

I have a `JupyterLab` notebook that I can export to `Reveal.js` slides just fine: it produces a nice `html` file that I am able to view in my browser. It looks like this:

[image: Exported_notebook]

Now I want to take that same notebook and start a live slideshow in `JupyterLab`, using `RISE`. But when I click on the *Render notebook* button (circled in the picture below), I get the following error:

[image: 404 : Not Found]

I am thinking that there must be something very basic that I have done wrong, but I am afraid that I have no idea what it is (I use `JupyterLab` with `Sagemath` kernel frequently when I teach, but I am just starting to use `Reveal.js` and `RISE`, so I am probably missing a lot of what is going on here).

Would anyone please have any pointers to help me fix the issue?

Thank you very much!